# Are there approaches to show that GR and QFT actually are unifable (without looking for a concrete ToE formalism)?

Tags: theory-of-everything, unified-theories

In mathematics, you can show that some problems are unprovable or have no solution at all and you also have the tool of proof by contradiciton, and similar. But is any of this also applied in physics to find out whether GR and QFT can be unified *at all*?

Are there people/papers dealing with the question about whether a ToE is (not) possible at all? So, without actually looking for a concrete ToE, but only for a statement about whether it is possible to find one at all?

Comment: String theory is one unification of QM and GR, regardless of whether it is correct or not.

Comment: [What If Gravity is NOT Quantum?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aR77s9RLck)

Comment: @Ghoster Yes, and? AFAIK, String theory failed to become the ToE. How does this relate to my question?

Comment: *How does this relate to my question?* It proves that unification *is* possible, which is what you asked.

Comment: How does a failed theory prove something?